# Why not use a struct-based singleton in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, singleton, swift5

Why not use a struct-based singleton?

I created decodable struct-based singleton.

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    static var shared = Person()

    private(set) var name: String?
                 var age: Int?
   
    private init() {
    
    }

    mutating func initData(from data: Data) {
        if let person = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data) {
            self = person
        }
    }
}
```

init from other class like this:

```
Person.shared.initData(from: data)
```

and use parameters:

```
let name = Person.shared.name 
Person.shared.name = "MyName" //error


Person.shared.age  = 20
```

Is this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a struct fora singleton because `struct` is a value type so when you assign it to a variable you get a copy. This can be easily shown

```
struct Singleton {
    static var shared = Singleton()
    var value: Int

    private init() {
        value = 0
    }
}

Singleton.shared.value = 1
var otherSingleton = Singleton.shared
otherSingleton.value = 2
```

Now if we print the `value` of both

```
print(Singleton.shared.value, otherSingleton.value)
```

we get

> 1 2

So `otherSingleton` is clearly a separate instance so now we have 2 singletons :)

But if we simply change the type of `Singleton` to class that is a reference type and then run the same code the result of the print is

> 2 2

since it is the same instance we have changed the `value` property for.

Comment: Is it okay to use a struct-based singleton if I don't create and use a separate instance?

Comment: @user16114557 yes, you can do everything if you never do anything wrong ;) The point of using a singleton in the first place is that you can't make multiple instance by mistake and this can easily happen, maybe not today but sometime in the future. Also if you "know" you never make this mistake then you don't really need a Singleton, using `shared` is enough then.

Comment: It was helpful. thank you!